# rails 3.2.3 STI, AR subclasses not inheriting associations/reflections

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, single-table-inheritance

Rails 3.2.3

Here's the example that's confusing me:

```
    class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :toys
    end

    class Man < Person
    end

    class Woman < Person
      has_many :cookies, foreign_key: person_id
    end
```

Then this happens:

```
    Person.reflections.keys  # [:toys]
    Man.reflections.keys  # [:toys]
    Woman.reflections.keys  # [:cookies]
```

Please note that I expected `Woman.reflections.keys` to be `[:toys, :cookies]`

Further, if I do this:

```
    Person.new.keys  # []
    Man.new.keys  # []
    Woman.new.keys  # NoMethodError: undefined method `association_class' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out what was going on for me. I'm not exactly sure why the app loaded and ran without issue but then gave me this problem. Here's more info on my models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  DEFAULT_SUBCLASS = Woman  # <------
  has_many :toys
end

class Man < Person
end

class Woman < Person
  has_many :cookies, foreign_key: person_id
end
```

Rails wasn't throwing an error, it was just not fully loading the Person class prior to the Woman class I think. There's an issue here with both classes needed the other to load before they can load but I'm not sure why it resulted in my issue. I'd be curious to learn more. But maybe this will help someone experiencing something similar.